# Identify the pink mold infecting refrigerated lemons

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology

I made lemon juice 6 month ago.

- I just washed the lemon using brush and then cut them into pieces.
- Then I put one layer of lemon in the bottle followed by one layer of
  sugar
- Again one layer of lemon and one layer of sugar.
- Then I close the bottle and put it in the refrigerator.

When I opened it, I observed some pink colored mold on the lemon slices.

Can anyone can identify the mold or tell me how to identify it?

PS: in the 6 months, I never opened the bottle. The bottle was clean and I did not add water; just lemon and sugar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whatever it is, I would not consume the lemon juice. The chances of toxins being present are just too high.

Comment: It can be *Neurospora crassa*....cause the **fungus is pink**, **can live in anaerobic conditions**, & **can survive on carbohydrates, like sugar**...but it's only a wild guess.... The pickle in your case got spoiled because it got in contact with water, only a few drops, but enough to cause those scattered microbial infections...

Comment: The S.E is gradually becoming a "Show & Tell"-site...somebody or the other is watching a vid or a pic or something weird in their kitchens...& thinking " Let's-just-post-it-in-BiologyS.E-&-ask-for-an-answer"....

Comment: Additional details are necessary to answer this question. Can you please provide them?

Comment: I would say that it is very hard to impossible to identify a mold simply by photos. There are a number of different molds that can grow under the actual conditions.

Answer (score -1):

I checked [citrus diseases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_citrus_diseases) on wikipedia, then "ctrl+f" and typed in "pink mold". The result was [Gliocladium roseum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonostachys_rosea_f._rosea) which is really a pink mold, but it is hard to find any image of it, where it is on fruits... So this is just a guess. Btw. I think it is rarely possible to identify microorganisms just by checking an image of them.

Comment: citrus disease refers to mainly diseases on live citrus trees or fruits still on trees...the q is talking about a dead, refrigerated citrus...

Comment: @souvikbhattacharya "It colonizes living plants as an endophyte, digests material in soil as a saprophyte and is also known as a parasite of other fungi and of nematodes." - according to wikipedia. So I think it can survive on a dead lemon as well and likes anaerob conditions. Before cutting into slices the lemon was pretty alive (like every other fruit). The freezing not necessary kills microbes. Btw. I think it is impossible to find out what it is without laboratory tests...

Comment: If the mold was already there before pickling it...then why pickle it in the 1st place???....neway the q is pretty frustrating...why don't she try it out to find what actually it is,"great 1st hand experience"..;)